How to put display formulae into its previous line where space is sufficient?
Normally, a display formula takes up a separate line alone. This can sometimes be overly space consuming. Today, I found an article, and the display formulae are put in the same line as the text before it where space is sufficient. Here is a screenshot.

This article was typeset by 方正书版, a Chinese software. I wonder how we can do the same in LaTeX?

Can you provide a test file? Maybe a negative abovedisplayshortskip could be a hack

I am afraid no. As I said, a totally different typesetting software is used to produce the above result. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

You can surely produce a latex test document with a short text and an equation after that.

I believe it’s possible, because TeX makes \predisplaywidth available. On the other hand, I don’t find this an appealing idea.

You can mix text ant display math using flalign.  Centering the math takes a little more work (such as \rlap{text}&&).

@egreg Could you give an example for usage?

@youthdoo I said that I believe it's possible, not that I'm going to try something that I find typographically very dubious. Sorry.

I don't think I'd recommend this, but here is a solution: use \displaystyle inside the math environment $$. Then you can use some code to get equation labels. Here is an example:

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

Here is some text and $\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}=n$ some 
equations in the running text that fit into the text 
$\displaystyle \Vec{F}=m\frac{\dd \Vec{p}}{\dd t}$.
And I can keep going. If I want to number them, I can use some fancy code to get equation numbers: 
$\displaystyle \frac{\dd \sqrt{\frac{Q}{M}} X}{\dd X}=0 \quad \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{myeq}$. 
This can go on and on... here is a ref to the previous eq: 
\ref{myeq}.

\end{document}

See Labelled in-line equation for how to label in line equations.

Thanks, but the key point is that although those display formulae do not occupy a line alone, they are still in the center.
